# Prove complex sequence converges using $\epsilon-N$ definition of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, complex-numbers

Could somebody please prove that the complex sequence $a_n=\frac{(ni+2)^2}{n^2i}$ converges to $i$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a suitable $N$ such that whenever $n>N$ $|a_n-i|<\epsilon$

Comment: You should detail what you tried and why you got stuck in your question.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*:

Prove that $|a_n-i|$ converges to $0$, that is:

$$\left|\frac{(ni+2)^2}{n^2i}-i\right|=\left|\frac{4-n^2+4ni+n^2}{n^2i}\right|=\sqrt{\left(\frac4n\right)^2+\left(\frac4{n^2}\right)^2}\to0$$

Comment: I think this would be more understandable if you added $=|\frac{4+4ni}{n^2i}|=|\frac{4}{n^2i}+\frac{4}{n}|$.

Comment: Also, the absolute value should have$=\sqrt{...}$, though the result is still correct.

Comment: $\left|\frac{(ni+2)^2}{n^2i}-i\right|=\left|\frac{4-n^2+4ni+n^2}{n^2i}\right|=\frac{\left|4-n^2+4ni+n^2\right|}{n^2}\leq \frac{4+4n}{n^2}$ but from here I don't know how to find a suitable $N$ from here